# Use of '判宦' in 九郎判宦義経

Tags: translation, meaning, kanji, readings

A simple name cartouche 九郎判宦義経 uses '判宦' instead of '判官'. I assume it is supposed to be read *Kurō Hōgan Yoshitsune*. Yoshitsune received the title *Kurō Hōgan* (九郎**判官**) from the Imperial Court; sometimes you see his name written as *Minamoto Kurō Yoshitsune* (源九郎義経) without the *Hōgan*; the term "sympathy for a tragic hero," *Hōgan-biiki* (判官贔屓) comes from Yoshitsune's title. Can anyone shed light on the 宦/官 substitution — is this common?

In general dictionary searches, I noted that *kangan* 宦官 (かんがん) is the noun for "eunuch". Assuming *Hō**gan*** is correct, then is it a simple matter that 宦 has a *kan* かん sound (as evidenced in ***kan**gan* 宦官) and a *gan* がん sound (as evidenced in *Hō**gan*** 判宦)?

Wiktionary gives the following readings for 宦:

Goon: げん (gen)

Kan’on: かん (kan)

Kun: つかえる (**tsuka**eru, 宦える); まなぶ (manabu)

Wiktionary gives the following readings for 官:

Goon: かん (kan)

Kan’on: かん (kan)

Kun: つかさ (tsukasa, 官); おおやけ (ōyake, 官)

Elsewhere:

宦 = "official", Kun: つかさ *tsukasa*, On: カン

官 = "government service; the bureaucracy​", かん *kan*

官 = "office; official", ​Archaism, つかさ *tsukasa*

[image: cartouche]

Comment: (1) Rather than saying that 宦 has a がん sound, it's worth considering the がん sound as [rendaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku), in the same way that かな becomes がな in ひらがな or かみ becomes がみ in おりがみ; (2) What historical background is this, and what are the views of the artist? It may help shed some light on why 宦 was chosen. 宦 and 官 are synonyms to a large degree, but at least in Chinese historical literature 宦 appears more in texts about shady court politics, and 宦 has an additional meaning of "eunuch" that 官 does not have. It may be some kind of wordplay and a subtle insult.

Comment: You asked about context: the name cartouche is one of many cartouches from a Yoshikazu print 大物浦難風之圖 showing Taira no Tomomori (_Tomomori no rei_, 知盛之霊) rising up against Yoshitsune (_Kurō Hōgan Yoshitsune_, 九郎判宦義経). As such—and though I am not familiar with the _Gikeiki_ (義経記, The Chronicle of Yoshitsune) or the Noh play _Funa Benkei_  (船弁慶, Benkei in a Boat) from which this narrative is supposed to derive—I assume there are no negative connotations with the selection of 宦 over 官.

Comment: <https://www.orientaloutpost.com/dictionary.php?q=officer>: Chinese magistrate (during Tang and Song dynasties); mythological underworld judge;  and Japanese (1) (はんがん only) judge; magistrate; (2) (archaism) (See 四等官,尉・じょう・1) 3rd grade official (ritsuryo system); assistant district officer; inspector; (surname) Hangan; (person) Minamoto-no-Yoshitsune (nickname)

Comment: 「じょう」is a *kun'yomi* for「判官」and「尉」, but it looks like a Chinese-derived word, and I'm going to assume that it comes from the first character of「[上官](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8A%E5%AE%98)」. I can't be sure of the answer to your question, but there are no Japanese (or Chinese) examples that I can find of「判宦」, nor can I find an example of「宦」being a *kokkun* reading for anything, so I feel that this character is either a mistake or a wordplay. Note that such a wordplay or mistake can only be made in Japanese, as「宦」and「官」do not sound the same in Chinese.

Comment: Correction: 「じょう」comes from「[丞](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%9E)」; see [`「じょう」は唐代に一部の官庁で三等官の呼称だった「丞」の借音`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9B%E7%AD%89%E5%AE%98#%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%9B%E7%AD%89%E5%AE%98%E5%88%B6). In any case,「判官」is not written as「判宦」in orthodox literature.